# ggplot and label: How to shift the text outside?

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, border, distance

I'm trying to draw map. Is there a way to write the name of the cities outside their borders? Looking for an answer i've found the package `ggrepel`, but it seems that it has not been implemented also for geographical maps, indeed if I write

```
right_join(prov2022, dataset, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `real wage`))+
  geom_sf(data = ~ subset(., COD_REG == 7 | COD_REG >= 1  & COD_REG <= 3)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  geom_sf_text(data = ~ subset(., COD_REG == 7 ), aes(label = city_name), size = 3) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( "#FFFFFF","#FFFF00", "#FF0000", "#000000")) +
  geom_blank()+
  geom_sf_text_repel(aes(label = city_name))
```

R answers

```
Error in geom_sf_text_repel(aes(label = city_name)) : 
  could not find function "geom_sf_text_repel"
```

Do you know any other way shift the label `city_name` from within the borders to the outside ?

Comment: A `geom_sf_text_repel` was implemented in the `ggsflabel` package: https://github.com/yutannihilation/ggsflabel. Note however that this package was archived recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nudge_x` and `nudge_y` inside `geom_sf_text` to move the labels an arbitrary amount:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_sf(fill = "white") +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = lab), size = 5, nudge_x = 0.05, nudge_y = 0.05)
```

[image]

If you prefer to control the exact position of each label, these parameters take vectorized inputs:

```r
ggplot(df) +
  geom_sf(fill = "white") +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = lab), size = 5, 
               nudge_x = c(0, -0.05, 0.05), 
               nudge_y = c(0, -0.05, 0.05))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
library(sf)

df <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)))) |>
  list(st_point(c(0.25, 0.25)), st_point(c(0.75, 0.75))) |>
  st_sfc(crs = "WGS84") |>
  st_as_sf() |>
  within(lab <- c("", "City 1", "City 2"))
```

Comment: hi Allan, thanks for the answer! I've tried to add `nudge_x = 0.05, nudge_y = 0.05` in my script, but nothing happens... i've also used different values but same result

Comment: @io_boh did you use it inside `geom_sf_text`? If your sf's crs uses metres, you might need to nudge by a few thousand to see any difference.

Comment: you were right!! I needed to nudge by a few thousand to see the difference! Thank you were much